# How To: Lex V2 Fulfillment Updates in Twilio WhatsApp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, twilio, twilio-api, amazon-lex

I am using Lex V2 with Twilio WhatsApp. I want to use fulfillment updates, where when the fulfillment Lambda function is called, it sometimes takes too long to run. So, every 5 seconds I want to send the user "please wait..." in Twilio WhatsApp until the fulfillment Lambda function finishes running.

I read through using [streaming API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/using-streaming-api.html) and [starting streaming conversations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lexv2/latest/dg/start-stream-conversation.html), but I am still not sure how I can apply that to Twilio. Can someone suggest what I can do?